# maven release -> peer not authenticated

Tags: java, maven, svn, https, release

I'm experimenting a bit with releasing my software (I've never done this before) and so far I've been able to execute mvn release:prepare. As I'm executing release:perform I get the following error:

```
[INFO] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plug
in:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project img2stl: Failed to deploy artifacts: C
ould not transfer artifact nl.byterendition:img2stl:jar:0.9 from/to byterenditio
n-releases (https://localhost:443/svn/repo/releases): peer not authenticated ->
[Help 1]
```

I've set up a local password protected svn repository at localhost:443, so I added the following to my settings.xml in my .m2 folder

EDITED TO INCLUDE Edwin Buck's answer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>byterendition-releases</id>
            <username>username</username>
            <password>password</password>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>byterendition-snapshots</id>
            <username>username</username>
            <password>password</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

This is the useful section of my pom:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>byterendition-releases</id>
        <url>https://localhost:443/svn/repo/releases</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>byterendition-snapshots</id>
        <url>https://localhost:443/svn/repo/snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

How can I get maven to access the svn repository?

Ok, as Edwin Buck suggested I shouldn't use localhost, but since I haven't been able to get it to work otherwise I thought I'd try this using a remote SVN server I use for work. Now I get a different error:

```
[INFO] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plug
in:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project img2stl: Failed to deploy artifacts: C
ould not transfer artifact nl.byterendition:img2stl:jar:0.9.5 from/to byterendit
ion-releases (https://svn.science.ru.nl/repos/estens/releases/): Failed to trans
fer file: https://svn.science.ru.nl/repos/estens/releases/nl/byterendition/img2s
tl/0.9.5/img2stl-0.9.5.jar. Return code is: 409, ReasonPhrase: Conflict. -> [Hel
p 1]
```

Again I can access this repo from Eclipse. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It's a bad idea to change your original question like you did, now the thread doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 71):

Since version 3.0.5 Maven checks the SSL certificate on https connections. You can temporarily fix this by adding the command line parameters

```
-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true
```

Installing the SSL certificate into your JRE should permanently fix the issue.

Official documentation: http://maven.apache.org/wagon/wagon-providers/wagon-http/

Comment: This started happening for me after updating to Mavericks on MacOSX, and this turned out to be the solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428901/how-to-preserve-the-cacerts-keystore-on-mac-across-updates

Comment: The Maven release plugin does not propagate system properties to the maven release build. Thus one needs to add
`<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
  <arguments>-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true</arguments>  
  </configuration>
</plugin>`
to ones settings.xml
[see notatube.blogspot.nl](http://notatube.blogspot.nl/2010/10/passing-properties-to-maven-release.html)

Comment: It also solved my problem when Gradle couldn't reach the maven repo.

Comment: I add <plugin>..<arguments>... into pom.xml instead of settings.xml. Adding to settings.xml does not work for me.

Comment: And how shall we install that SSL certificate?

Answer (score 13):

**Step 1.** Download the certificate in DER format *.cer (/X.509 .cert) file to your local dir

(You can do this from your browser; For Chrome Click on the Lock symbol, Show Ceritficate --> Copy to File)

**Step 2.** Import it to Java trust store

> \Program_Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\lib\security>%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin\keytool
> -v  -alias mavensrv -import -file d:\temp\apacher.cer -keystore trust.jks

**Step 3.** Give the path to maven as environment variables

> set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx512m
> -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security/trust.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security/trust.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=changeit

Comment: I had done steps 1 and 2 before having red this answer and it had solved some ```ReasonPhrase:Forbidden``` and ```peer not authenticated``` problems. Next the ```peer not authenticated``` happened again and adding ```-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=%JRE_HOME%\lib\security\cacerts -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit``` didn't solved it. Thanks to your step 3 I've added ```-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=%JRE_HOME%\lib\security\cacerts -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=changeit``` too solving my problems. (Where ```JAVA_HOME=C:\Programmi\java\jdk1.7.0_25``` and ```JRE_HOME=%JAVA_HOME%\jre```)

Comment: This worked for me. More instructions can be found here: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-repository-ssl.html Additionaly, if the certificate from your company is not signed (it's insecure), you need to add the following options anyway `-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true`

Answer (score 3):

Your entry in `settings.xml` is for a server id of `localhost` but you are accessing repositories with id(s) of `byterendition-releases` and `byterendition-snapshots`.

This means that maven won't recogonize and associate the credentials with these two servers, because they have different "identities".  You will need settings.xml entries for `byterendition-releases` and `byterendition-snapshots`.

Now if you added an entry like

```
    <server>
        <id>byterendition-releases</id>
        <username>user</username>
        <password>password</password>
    </server>
```

Then maven would meet the https authentication challenge to `byterendition-releases` with a username of `user` and a password of `password`, because it has a server credential entry for `byterendition-releases`.

You'll also have to add in an additional entry for `byterendition-snapshots`, or set it to have the same server id as `byterendition-releases`.

--- Edited to keep up with the updated question ---

You are reaching for your repository with a `localhost` URL.  While this might work if your repository is really on the same host machine, there are lots of reasons why it might not work.

1. The SVN repository is on a remote SVN server, so this will fail when developing elsewhere than the remote server.
2. The HTTP server is not configured to resolve localhost exactly the same way that it might resolve an external request.

Either way, ditch localhost.  If you can't get a stable DNS name for the machine, even putting in an IP address is a better choice.  If your SVN server is on DHCP, then invest the time into getting DynamicDNS working (but really, you should get a static IP for a server if you can).

Comment: Thanks, I did that, but it didn't help, I still get the exact same error. I edited the post to reflect the updated settings.xml. How can I check if maven actually uses the settings.xml file to see if maybe that is the problem?

Comment: Try running maven with the `-X` option will put out a lot of data which can be useful in determining whether you are connecting to the right server, with or without credentials.  Finally, if you have access to the server, check to see if you fail authentication on the back end, as there might be other networking issues at play here.

Comment: Hm, seems maven is using the correct file: [DEBUG] Reading user settings from C:\Users\username\.m2\settings.xml

Comment: I added the repo location in Eclipse and there I could access it using the same credentials I put into the settings.xml file

Comment: Odds are that the SSL cert is an issue.  Maybe it has a lot to do with attempting to reach you machine as `localhost`.  Odds are your cert is signed for you machine's hostname, which probably isn't localhost.  If on a Linux-ish system look in /var/log/secure for failures, they are often "descriptive enough" to find the next part of the solution.

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/escline/InstallCert provides the necessary tools and provides a step by step instruction on how to import a remote certificate into the system-wide certificate store.

Answer (score 2):

I found that the Java version can make a difference here.

With Maven 3.0.5 I was getting this error with Java 6, but switching to Java 7 (or newer) resolved it for me.

Comment: I am on Java 7 and maven 3.3, I still have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a SSL problem when connecting to the server. Maybe before the username and password check.

Did you config the svn server with SSL client auth? This means you need to send a client certificate to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I've had lot of security issues after upgrading to OSX Mavericks

- SSL problem with Amazon AWS
- peer not authenticated with Maven and Eclipse
- trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

I applied this JAVA update and it fixed all my issues:
http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US

Answer (score 0):

I'm using maven 3.5.3, and I choose to temporarily fix this SSL issue by adding the command line parameters according to above answers. But the parameters's format seems changed a little.

```
-D maven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -D maven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true
```

Sorry I can't comment @Alex Punnen's answer, so I have to write a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using maven 3.6.0. All proposed solutions (using `-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true`, `-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true`, update CA store) did not work for me. Actually the deployment failed not on the first module but on the ~25ish or so, and was successful for all previous modules. Thus I assumed that in general the SSL handling was ok and there was general issue in the local <> server connection or certificates.

Leaving me quite confused for some time, I today stumbled across [this jacoco issue](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/269) where they mention [the `deployAtEnd` parameter](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-mojo.html#deployAtEnd). Adding this parameter to my pom.xml as part of the deploy plugin configuration solved the issue for me.

However, I'm yet not clear on why the deployment failed on some later module and not on the first already.