# "Peer Not Authenticated" in maven when trying to run a job in JENKINS

Tags: maven

When I try running a maven job in Jenkins, the build is not successful.

The error message in the console displays the following :

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-       resources-plugin/2.5/maven-resources-plugin-2.5.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.640s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Aug 20 11:21:36 EST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/16M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
mavenExecutionResult exceptions not empty
message : Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its     dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for         org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
cause : Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-    resources-plugin:jar:2.5
Stack trace : 


org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:129)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:142)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:261)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:185)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecution(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:152)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecutions(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:139)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:116)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:129)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.BuilderCommon.resolveBuildPlan(BuilderCommon.java:92)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.main(Maven3Launcher.java:79)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:329)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)
at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:158)
at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:100)
at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:66)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:296)
at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:186)
at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:279)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:115)
... 33 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): peer not authenticated
at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:538)
at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:216)
at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:193)
at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:281)
... 36 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): peer not authenticated
at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:951)
at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:941)
at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:669)
at org.sonatype.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:60)
... 3 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: peer not authenticated
at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http4.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:892)
at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:116)
at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:601)
... 4 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:397)
at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:126)
at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:628)
at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http4.ConfigurableSSLSocketFactoryDecorator.createLayeredSocket(ConfigurableSSLSocketFactoryDecorator.java:57)
at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.updateSecureConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:232)
at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.layerProtocol(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:401)
at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.establishRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:842)
at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:649)
at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:480)
at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http4.AbstractHttpClientWagon.execute(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:746)
at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http4.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:886)
... 8 more
channel stopped
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -agentlib:jvmhook
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xrunjvmhook -    Xbootclasspath/a:C:\PROGRA~1\HP\QUICKT~1\bin\JAVA_S~1\classes;C:\PROGRA~1\HP\QUICKT~1\bin\J    AVA_S~1\classes\jasmine.jar
Finished: FAILURE
```

I'm able to get to know the root cause of the error is some authentication issue("peer not authenticated"). But not able to get it resolved as I am not aware what authetication I need to key in and where to key in.

Additional details : I am using Maven 3.0.3 and JDK 1.7

Thanks in advance for your time in helping me resolving the issue. Let me know if you need any additional info.

Thanks

Answer (score 35, accepted):

When using SSL to connect to maven repositories you'll need to make sure that the certificates for the repository are trusted by the JVM running maven. Refer to the [Guide to Remote repository access through authenticated HTTPS](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-repository-ssl.html).

Also, as mentioned by rec in an answer to [maven release -> peer not authenticated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691985/mven-release-peer-not-authenticated), with newer versions of maven you can disable the certificate validation of the [maven http wagon](http://maven.apache.org/wagon/wagon-providers/wagon-http/) temporarily to confirm if the certificate is indeed the source of the problem:

```
-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Drew. I was using Maven 3.0.4 in which I was facing this issue. I configured Maven 3.0.3 which resolved the issue  surprisingly. Though this is a temporary solution, I wish to use the latest version of Maven in my project.  I strongly believe the JVM which Maven 3.0.3 is pointing to is the same JVM 3.0.4 was also pointing. If that is the case, is there any issue with JVM 3.0.4? Please let us know as this will be beneficial to the MAVEN community. Thanks once again Drew.

Comment: [Maven 3.0.5](http://maven.apache.org/docs/3.0.5/release-notes.html)  fixes SSL issues with 3.0.4

Comment: Thanks for the info Drew. Will try with Maven 3.0.5

Comment: cd c%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\security>

%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin\keytool -v  -alias mavensrvNewCer -import -file d:\pathtoexportedcertificate.cer -keystore trust.jks

Answer (score 2):

### **Solution 4 “Peer Not Authenticated” while adding maven "jitpack.io" in app's gradle.build.**

Simple solution is install java 8 if you have lower version. 
We tried with Oracle java8 and it works. :)

Note : Tried a lot of solutions those are on stackoverflow.com but none of them work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have set Java Home - JAVA_HOME env variable and using it to run maven;

Pre-req is that you have exported the .cer certificate (via browser ex)

```
cd %JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\security

%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin\keytool -v  -alias mavensrvNewCer -import -file d:\pathtoexportedcertificate.cer -keystore trust.jks 



set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx512m -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security/trust.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security/trust.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=changeit

mvn install
```