# Apache Spark 1.4.1 Build Failed

Tags: maven, apache-spark, maven-assembly-plugin, apache-spark-1.4

I have download Apache Spark 1.4.1 from the official site. As follows:

[image]

I don't have `hadoop` installed in my machine.
Apache provides build command. So, I tried to start building the project using following command
`build/mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.4 -Dhadoop.version=2.4.0 -DskipTests clean package`

But build was failed with the following error:

```
[INFO] Spark Project External Kafka Assembly ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project YARN Shuffle Service ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------   ---
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.840s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jul 29 10:43:04 IST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/43M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:jar:1.4: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:pom:1.4 from/to central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2): peer not authenticated -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

I am new with `Apache Spark` please give suggestions.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Peer Not Authenticated" in maven when trying to run a job in JENKINS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18325724/peer-not-authenticated-in-maven-when-trying-to-run-a-job-in-jenkins)

Answer (score 0):

since it is precompiled Binary distribution you have downloaded. you do not need to compile it again using maven2. just put it on path and use it directly.