# SOAP error 5001 (peer not authenticated)

Tags: soap, soapui, soap-client

I ran soap action API (PerFormTopUp or RefillT API). 
All necessary parameters in request are correct.

1. Destination IP are correct including port #
2. Network wise, from router to FW it was sent to destination(LB)
3. Telnet, traceroute and ping also good

**Problem:**
In response XML logs, I noticed error 5001 - *Java Embedded Fault: peer not authenticated*

What is this 5001 error? Can someone help? 

Server: oracle (AIA/SOA)

Comment: Please see if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691985/maven-release-peer-not-authenticated) helps.

Answer (score 0):

The below post might help you

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/httpfiddler/ZQNk6pUgDOo