# Non-resolvable parent POM exception thrown while running maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jenkins

I'm new to Jenkins plugin development,and trying to create a Jenkins plugin by using maven project, and using eclipse as IDE.

The below is pom.xml file structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
    <groupId>io.jenkins.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>JenkinPluginDev</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>hpi</packaging>
    <properties>
        <jenkins.version>2.7.3</jenkins.version>
        <java.level>7</java.level>
    </properties>
    <name>TODO Plugin</name>
    <description>TODO</description>
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>MIT License</name>
            <url>https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT</url>
        </license>
    </licenses>
    <!-- Assuming you want to host on @jenkinsci:
    <url>https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/TODO+Plugin</url>
    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:git://github.com/jenkinsci/${project.artifactId}-plugin.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:jenkinsci/${project.artifactId}-plugin.git</developerConnection>
        <url>https://github.com/jenkinsci/${project.artifactId}-plugin</url>
    </scm>
    -->
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>repo.jenkins-ci.org</id>
            <url>https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>repo.jenkins-ci.org</id>
            <url>https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

And the maven project had some error in POM.xml file near to "Parent" tag.

I tried to run the maven goal to resolve the issue but its failed to   build and observed below error message in console.

> Downloading:
>   https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/org/jenkins-ci/plugins/plugin/3.4/plugin-3.4.pom
>   [ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1] [ERROR]
>
> [ERROR]   The project io.jenkins.plugins:JenkinPluginDev:1.0
>
> (C:\jenkinPluginDevelopment\JenkinPluginDev\pom.xml) has 1 error
>
> [ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not transfer artifact
>   org.jenkins-ci.plugins:plugin:pom:3.4 from/to repo.jenkins-ci.org
>   (https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/): peer not authenticated and
>   'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 4, column 13 ->
>   [Help 2]
>
> [ERROR]  [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors,
>   re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>
> [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X
>   switch to enable full debug logging.
>
> [ERROR]  [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, >please read the following articles:
>
> [ERROR] [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
>   [ERROR] [Help 2]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException

Any leads...

Answer (score 0):

Is this project dependent on another parent project?

The error `parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 4, column 13` indicates you do not have a parent pom xml.

Can you post your folder structure?

Comment: OP is explicitly using non-local pom because of `<relativePath />`.This pom comes from Jenkins's artifactory server and is not part of OPs project.

Answer (score 0):

Real problem is that SSL certificate present by repo.jenkins-ci.org is not in your trusted ca database (peer not authenticated).

You could update your JRE ca keystore or install CA certificate  manually (using keytool).
There is also possibility that your local clock are too far off, so certificate validation is failing (even if CA cert is present in keystore). Try to re-run maven with `-e` which will produce more verbose error.

As last option (not recommended) is to run maven with disabled SSL check (details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17734427/1121249))

Answer (score 0):

I am right now developing a jenkins plugin.

At the beginning, I had the same problems : make a clean and correct pom.xml

After check dozens of github official jenkins plugin repositories, I was able to create a very good starter pom.xml :

This is my current pom and it works perfectly (java 8 , eclipse, maven , linux, etc)

https://gist.github.com/jrichardsz/e5d7b67475f1625f4487740708af285d

Also, you can check this official pugin github repositories, to search poms:

- https://github.com/jenkinsci/cloudbees-folder-plugin.git
- https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-job-plugin.git
- https://github.com/jenkinsci/build-pipeline-plugin.git