# Maven build, broken dependency

Tags: java, maven

When building a java project, Maven is failing on one dependency, while it wasn't 6 months ago.

The original error was:

```
Failed to execute goal on project bdpreviewer: Could not resolve dependencies for project bdpreviewer:bdpreviewer:jar:3.6.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies for [xxx]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for Mozilla:Glue:jar:1.9: Could not transfer artifact Mozilla:Glue:pom:1.9 from/to com.teamdev (http://maven.teamdev.com/repository/products): peer not authenticated -> [Help 1]
```

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17734427/2398993), I added the following Maven option:

```
-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true
```

I've got now the following error

```
Failed to execute goal on project bdpreviewer: Could not resolve dependencies for project bdpreviewer:bdpreviewer:jar:3.6.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies for [xxx]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for Mozilla:Glue:jar:1.9: Could not transfer artifact Mozilla:Glue:pom:1.9 from/to com.teamdev (http://maven.teamdev.com/repository/products): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]
```

What I observe is that

- The `http://maven.teamdev.com/repository/products` repository does not contain any Mozilla/Glue folder
- My local `.m2\repository` folder does contain the Glue-1.9.jar but not the corresponding .pom file.

Latest: I'm using Maven 3.0.5

How can I resolve this ?

Comment: See if a suitable replacement is available in maven central.

Comment: What is "Mozilla:Glue"? Looks like a dodgy dependency, maybe malicious?

Comment: Mozilla:Glue is part of MozSwing, a way to integrate Firefox into a Swing application. An old libraries set. I temporarily solved the issue by removing the link to the teamdev repository in the pom.xml. Maven is no longer looking for the Mozilla:Glue:pom:1.9 and it is working fine. I guess I should now secure these libraries in some local repository to ensure they are not removed by a .m2/repository cleansing.