# Java "peer not authenticated" Error When Decompiling MinecraftForge 1.8.9

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

When try to run gradle tasks for the [MinecraftForge MDK](https://files.minecraftforge.net/net/minecraftforge/forge/index_1.8.9.html), I get a `peer not authenticated` error.
I am assuming this has to do with my `cacerts` file, but I have replaced that with fresh versions from [Java's JDK](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html) and it didn't help.

Error:

```
> A problem occurred configuring root project '1.8'.
 > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
  > Could not resolve net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:2.1-SNAPSHOT.
  > Required by:
  > :1.8:unspecified
   > Could not resolve net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:2.1-SNAPSHOT.
    > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/net/minecraftforge/gradle/ForgeGradle/2.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.
     > Could not GET 'http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/net/minecraftforge/gradle/ForgeGradle/2.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml'.
      > peer not authenticated
```

I would like to add that the decompilation process previously worked on my machine and it doesn't work now. This must be a change *I* made because I am still using the same version of Forge.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [maven release -> peer not authenticated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691985/maven-release-peer-not-authenticated)

Answer (score 0):

If you have this same error, go to gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties and change `distributionUrl` to a later version (like `https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.8.3-all.zip`)

Answer (score 0):

Something that worked for me was my previous JDK was 1.8.0_101, I changed it to 1.8.0_271, that fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

Similar to SecretAgent's answer, I had to update my JDK, but I had to do it not just in my project settings in IntelliJ IDEA but also for Gradle itself in Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle > Gradle JVM.